# Sampling on a logarithmic scale

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, metropolis-hastings

I have to draw samples (variance parameter) based on a Gaussian kernel but on a logarithmic scale. I have no clue how to implement that as a part of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

In particular, I have a posterior distribution $\pi(a)$ whereas $\pi(a)$ is very stiff with respect to a. Therefore samples for a should be drawn on a logarithmic scale and based on random walk.

That means I do not need $\zeta^* \sim N(\zeta^i,\sigma)$ but $\zeta^* \sim 10^{(N(\zeta^i,\sigma))}$ with respect to $\pi(\zeta)$.

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

The question is unclear as stated: Do you mean that you have to sample a posterior $\pi(\sigma)$ on $\sigma>0$ and use a Gaussian random-walk proposal $\mathcal{N}(\log\sigma,\tau^2)$ on $\log\sigma$ within a Metropolis-Hastings framework?

In that case, the Metropolis-Hastings move is as follows:

1. Given $\sigma^t$, value of the Markov chain at iteration $t$, generate $\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(\log\sigma^t,\tau^2)$
2. Accept $\sigma^{t+1}=\exp\eta$ with probability
   \begin{align}\alpha(\sigma^t,\eta) &= \min\left\{1,\underbrace{\frac{\pi(\exp\eta)}{\pi(\sigma^t)}}_{\text{ratio of targets}}\times\underbrace{\frac{1/\sigma^t}{1/\exp\eta}}_\text{ratio of proposals}\right\}
   \end{align}else take $\sigma^{t+1}=\sigma^t$

so the difference with the usual random walk move is the inclusion of the Jacobian $$\frac{\text{d}\log \sigma}{\text{d}\sigma}=\frac{1}{\sigma}$$in the Metropolis-Hastings probability.

Comment: I think you might have flipped things around in the ratio of Jacobians?

Comment: Right you are, because this Jacobian is for the proposal, not for the target.

Comment: Are we sure this correct? the $\eta$ can be negative which would yield a negative acceptance probability.

Comment: @AOGSTA: well spotted, it should be $\exp(\eta)$.