# Normal-Gamma: Metropolis-Hastings on log-scale, but no Jacobian?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, metropolis-hastings

I am reading the paper by Griffin and Brown (2010) where at one step in their MCMC procedure they need to sample from the following conditional posterior:

$$
p(\lambda|\gamma, \Psi)\propto \pi(\lambda)\frac{1}{(2\gamma^2)^{p\lambda}(\Gamma(\lambda))^p}\left(\prod_{i=1}^p\Psi_i\right)^\lambda
$$

They say that $\lambda$

> can be updated using a Metropolis-Hastings random walk update on
>   $\log\lambda$. We propose $λ' = \exp\{\sigma^2_\lambda z\}\lambda$, where 
>   $z$ is standard normal then $\lambda'$ is accepted with probability $$
>  \min\left\{1, \frac{\pi(\lambda')}{\pi(\lambda)}\left(\frac{\Gamma(\lambda)}{\Gamma(\lambda')}\right)^p\left((2\gamma^2)^{-p}\prod_{i=1}^p\Psi_i\right)^{\lambda'-\lambda}\right\}
>  $$

My question: **why is there no term in the acceptance probability that accounts for the fact that we are proposing new draws on the logarithmic scale?**

See for example here: [Sampling on a logarithmic scale](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174985/sampling-on-a-logarithmic-scale) The paper, however, has more than 300 citations and I know several successful papers that have used the same type of Metropolis-Hastings procedure; therefore, I'm inclined to think I am missing something. But what?

---

Griffin and Brown (2010) Inference with normal-gamma prior distributions in regression problems, Bayesian Analysis, https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1340369797

Comment: I would also deem the Jacobian is indeed missing from the Metropolis-Hastings ratio.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks Xi'an, if you say so I feel more confident including the Jacobian part in my own implementation. Some limited experiments I have made show that it doesn't make a big difference, the posterior distribution of the first-level parameters ($\Psi$ here) is roughly the same. I guess that might be why they didn't notice they were using the wrong ratio (and why others haven't done so either when building onto their work).

Comment: It would not make much of a difference if the posterior is sufficiently concentrated.